# Adding a fixed-position view on top of a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITableViewController` inside a `UINavigationController`. I'm adding a "modal" subview to the `tableView`, which is a custom UIView when one of the rows is selected.

(It’s modal in spirit, not in the UIKit sense, since Apple doesn’t support modal views on iPhone, I’m adding it with a `[self.view addSubview:customView]` in my table view’s controller.)

I would like it to appear at the bottom of the screen and stay put there. I can get it to draw at the bottom, but once I scroll the table view, the view moves with it. Here are some illustrations:

Initial position (good):

[image]

Position after scrolling (bad):

[image]

I'm getting the bottom position by subtracting the height of all the chrome (navigation bar and status bar) as well as the height of the custom view from `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds`.

How can I get the custom view to stay put? Should I constantly be adjusting its frame when the table view is being scrolled?

Comment: You probably want to set this to the table view's footer view, not simply add it as a subview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best and most flexible option is to switch to using a view controller with the table view as a subview so that you can change its frame and add sibling views. Then, when you want to add a modal you can run an animation to move the table view out of the way and slide the modal view in.

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean replacing the UITableViewController with a plain UIViewController, adding the UITableView to it with `addSubview:` and conforming to the table view delegate and dataSource protocols?

Comment: Yes, then you can add other subviews as sibling of the table instead of subviews of the table

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewController.view` is an instance of `UITableView`. Means you added your custom view into a scroll view and that is why it scrolls. You can try to put your custom view into the `tableFooterView` property of the `UITableView`, which is the old school solution.

Personally I would create a container `UIViewController` and have `UITableViewController` be a sub viewController of it. Another sub viewController `UIViewController` or just a simple `UIView` could represent the footer.